# Limit dropdown options when the lookup column is a site column and has more values than are relevant

Tags: document-library, lookup-column, site-column, list-form

I have a list of projects on my parent site with two columns: `

1. Project
2. Category

I would like to use *Project* as a site column that looks up values from the aforementioned list so I can maintain a master list of projects on my parent site. I also have one sub-site per category, and I would like to create one or more document libraries on each sub site with the *Project* column so I can link documents to projects.

**If I add the *Project* column to a library in a subsite "Category A", how can I limit the available dropdown Project values to just those in "Category A"?**

I am thinking about customizing the form using InfoPath--not very familiar with the application just seems like it would be possible. Are there other methods that exist (JS, SP Designer,etc.)? Benefits and drawbacks of your suggestions?

Thanks!